# Excel: sum only the values which have certain tag

Tags: excel, database, automation

Im selling products to different countries in the world and Im using an excel table to document how many items I sold at a day and to which country the products will ship.

I made an example of that for you:

[image]

Now the table grows very big and I would like to have some overview how many products I sold to which countries.

I tried using something like

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("china",C1:C1000)),"True","")
```

but that does not work. Also I should mention that I am using Excel 2014. I dont have the newest functions of Excel 2019 avaible in my version.

So I need some code that sums the values of Bn if Cn contains the string china and so on.

Much more interesting would also be a possibility to plot the number of sold items for a country. Where the horizontal axis holds the date and the vertical axis holds the number of sold products.

Do you think you can help me out on this?

Comment: You should still have `SUMIFS()` which is the formula you want.

Comment: If you want to do a graph use a pivot graph.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume your data is in columns A, B and C.  To find out the total items sold to germany you would do as follows:

```
=SUMIFS(B:B, C:C, "germany")
```

Repeat for all countries.

Alternatively, you can highlight columns A to C and go to Insert > Pivot Table and it can do the work for you without formulas.  Put the Country in the "Row Values", the quantity sold in the "Values" and make sure the property of the quantity sold is set to SUM (mine defaults to COUNT) by clicking on the values item and pressing Value Field Settings.  If you place date in the columns section or filter, you can further filter the data.